# Android customView(extends AppCompatImageView) app:srcCompat not showing image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I made custom view just extends AppCompatImageView

```
class BadgeImageView: AppCompatImageView {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {

    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs:AttributeSet?):super(context, attrs){

    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs:AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr:Int):super(context, attrs,defStyleAttr){

    }
}
```

and when I used AppCompatImageView like..

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button_star" />
```

[AppCompatImageView Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zw4v.png)

and when I used BadgeImageView like..

```
  <com.my.proj.common.view.BadgeImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button_star" />
```

[BadgeImageView Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzldW.png)

As you can see, I just used a custom view instead of it, but it's not loading the image at all.

Why?

Comment: what exactly do you want ?? the image is showing properly in first screen shot

Comment: @D_K I want to make my own custom view. The result in first screenshot is not from a custom view, but from a built-in AppCompatImageView. In other words, I asked why even displaying an image fails before I can apply other tasks to my custom view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try out using this. I hope work fine.

```
class BadgeImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
            context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
    ) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { 


    }
```

Xml code snippet here.

```
<ui.components.BadgeImageView
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_reported_image"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                 app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/reportedTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
```

here is screenshot

[image: here is screenshot]

Comment: Doesn't work T3T..

Comment: Updated my answer